How to auto-respond to the forwarded Email-to-Case email?
When I create new Cases using the Email-to-Case the email which creates the Case has the forwarding email address created by Salesforce as the From. So, how do I send an auto-reply to the original senders ?

This is not well documented, but it looks like the Web Email field (SuppliedEmail) in the Case will contain the original sender's address when it's created by email-to-case.  Thus you can use the SuppliedEmail field in an auto-response rule.

N.B. If there's an existing (sole) Contact matching the email, the Case.Contact field points at that Contact

@David Cheng - how does this happen ? I guess it's through the Email Service created by the Email2Case forwarding email address ?
